# php-sql-smarty pagination

Tags: php, pagination, smarty

I have the following code :

```
$gemng = $db->query("SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY student_name ASC ");
while($ftmng = $db->fetch_array($gemng))
{
    $magn[] = $ftmng;
}
$tpl->assign('mn', $magn);
$db->free_result($gemng);
```

I want to display a result with only 20 student not more than that. and display others in pages. how can I do that ... can you fix the code and add the pagination code to it ? do not worry about the html file I will take care of it

Comment: did you ever try to  google for php pagination?

Comment: "fix my code" (AKA "do my job") question is apparently can be qualified as "too localized" one.

Comment: I just do not know how to do it. I am not a php pro. and I tried google ... it is too complicated !

Comment: **what is too complicated?** to go to google, type `php pagination` and hit Search? I did it right now. here are the titles: "PHP Pagination", "Simple Pagination in PHP tutorial" "Easy PHP Pagination". Aren't you satisfied? And you can find a plenty even by searching `PHP pagination smarty`

Comment: [Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager)

Comment: will I am using smarty template not only php

Comment: instead of waisting your time complaining about my question. you could have answered it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a simple tutorial](http://www.lotsofcode.com/php/smarty-pagination.htm) on how to code it. The comments discuss solution to additional problems.

Comment: what about php pagination only ? how can I do that ?

Comment: Something like this perhaps: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/306579

Answer (score 0):

For the Smarty 2 you can use [Paginate addon](http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/SmartyPaginate/). For the Smarty 3 I do not know ready to use solutions but you can convert it, just a good starting point to become a smarty guru.

Comment: what about php pagination only ? how can I do that ?